# Xamarin Forms IOS Failed to load assembly System.Net.Http.Primitive

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to do a release build for an IOS app using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2015.

Under the iOS Build menu in the properties of the app, If I set the Linker behaviour Link SDK assemblies only or Link all assemblies - I get the following build error:

> Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Net.Http.Primitives,
>   Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  BlackhawkPlatform.App.iOS

If I don't link any of the assemblies - the App builds fine but the output ipa is over 40mb big 0 uncompressed over 100mb and as such cannot be submitted to iTunes Connect.

I have the latest version installed of System.Net Client libraries and Xamarin Forms.

[image]

I have tried to skip the assembly link by using the command `--linkskip=System.Net.Http.Primitives` in the Additional mtouch argument box but that dos not work.

Any idea how I can get around this please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution which worked.

1. In Nuget package manager install the latest version of **Microsoft.BCL.Build** v1.0.21
2. then install the latest version of **Microsoft.Net.Http** v2.2.29

This worked for me.

Comment: This progressed me to a next error which was 'Failed to create the a fat library. Please review the build log. (MT5306)' I'll see if I can gather more on this.

Comment: I don't think it relates, but your answer seems to have got me further. Thanks.

Comment: Hi,  I have been finding issue where packages were not being unzipped properly.  I ended up removing the packages from the packages.config file and deleting them from the folder then re install them.  In some cases that worked as well.  I think there are still a few issues to resolve around Xamarin deployments though.

Comment: My other issue was nothing to do with this problem, so I can confirm your solution was correct. (My other issue was that I hadn't accepted my Xcode terms after an upgrade so it wouldn't deploy). Many hoops to jump through hey? Many thanks @loanburger

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread... but here is what I found missing in my ios.csproj file

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Yes that's what "should" get added when the Nuget Package is installed.