# Cannot load System.Net.Http.Primitives in Xamarin iOS

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I have an older Xamarin forms project that I've updated, that uses Microsoft Azure's Mobile App Services (previously used Azure Mobile Services).

Was working fine, but after a clean and rebuild I now get this error whenever attempting to run it (I'm using Xamarin Studio)

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client and SQLiteStore are at version 2.0.1.  I've tried removing and readding the assembly via NuGet, without any luck.

Has anyone seen this issue or resolved it?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926640/xamarin-forms-ios-failed-to-load-assembly-system-net-http-primitive ?

Comment: I did - however both Microsoft.BCL.Build 1.0.21 and Microsoft.Net.Http 2.2.29 are already in the project, and I still have an error that

Error CS0012 The type 'HttpMessageHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin iOS (monotouch) depends on System.Net.Http.Primitives version **4.2.29.0**, while version **1.5.0.0** is for platform portable-net40+sl4+win8+wp71+wpa81. As [Eric Hedstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775398/eric-hedstrom) commented, have you tried the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927125/873234) answer?

Comment: I had, but was still getting errors.  However I believe I found a workaround below.

Comment: Update - looks like the workaround does not.

I've added both Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.21 and Microsoft.Net.Http, however still get an error that The type `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly `System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' (CS0012) 

Checking to see if it's a conflict with ModernHttpHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Solution here wound up being recreating the Xamarin projects, and relinking the portable class library of the old project to it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error in my solution with Xamarin.iOS native project which is using `ModernHttpHandler`.

Try adding a reference to standard Mono `System.Net.Http` in csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
```

For more details take a look at [this blog post](http://byteloom.marek-mierzwa.com/mobile/2017/06/06/cannot-find-referenced-system-net-http-httpclienthandler.html).