# Xamarin linker error with AWSSDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-s3, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin forms mobile project (Android and iOS).

When I try to install the AWSSDK.S3 to access Amazon services, I get the following linker error when trying to build iOS:

Failed to resolve "System.Void Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AESEncryptionPutObjectStream::.ctor(System.IO.Stream,System.Byte[],System.Byte[])" reference from "AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604"

..Android build has a similar error.

I have the following libraries installed:

AWSSDK.S3  v3.1.1.1
AWSSDK.Core v3.3.4
AWSSDK.SecurityToken v3.3.0.2
AWSSDK.CognitolIdenity v3.3.0.2
AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider v3.3.1.2
PCLCrypto v2.0.147
PCLStorage v1.0.2

the only code in my project is:

```
 var amazonClient = new AmazonS3Client();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I would recommend that you go through your assemblies and `linkskip` some of these custom assemblies. That way you can keep `Link SDK Assemblies` and resolve your issue. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/#linkskip

Comment: I understand linkskip, any ideas on what assemblies to skip to fix missing call to Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.AESEncryptionPutObjectStream from AWSSDK.Core?

Comment: Start with linkskipping everything and then work your way down. I am not familiar with this library and thus I won't be much of help here unless I can decompile it. But I challenge you to use process of elimination here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turns out to be found here:

[Xamarin Forms IOS Failed to load assembly System.Net.Http.Primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35926640/xamarin-forms-ios-failed-to-load-assembly-system-net-http-primitive)

even though its a different assembly error, the fix is the same:

- update all the AWS.Core to the latest version: v3.3.6 in my case
- install Microsoft.Bcl.Build v1.0.21
- install Microsoft.Net.Http v2.2.29

Answer (score 0):

possible (bad) workaround that seems to work:

change in Linker Options/Linker behavior:

to: Don't link

instead of: Link SDK Assemblies only

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to AWSSDK.S3 V3.1.10 worked for me, done using the NuGet manager in Visual Studio. =)

Comment: How did you do it? Please complete your answer

Comment: @Daniel, NuGet lets you roll back to any version of a package, you just need to select the one you want in the dropdown

Comment: From Visual Studio Go to: Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution -> Click the "Installed" tab ->Select AWSSDK.S3 -> On the right hand side, select your project and then the Version from the dropdown below that -> Click Install -> Done