# awssdk.s3 throws System.MissingMethodException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xamarin.forms, aws-sdk

I am trying to use AWS S3 bucket from a Xamarin.Forms(v3.1.0.697729) app. However, I am getting the following exception-

> System.MissingMethodException: void
>   Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client..ctor(Amazon.RegionEndpoint)

Code I used -

```
var bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.USEast1;
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);                   
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);    
await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(stream, "<bucket name>, <key name>);
```

Steps to reproduce -

1. Create a new Xamarin.Forms project for iOS and Android
2. Add nuget package `awssdk.s3` (3.3.25)
3. Add the code above in a function and call that function on a button
   click.
4. Set Android as startup project
5. Hit F5 to run the project
6. You'll get an exception `System.MissingMethodException: void
   Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client..ctor(Amazon.RegionEndpoint)`

The same code works in .NET Core console application.

I have already tried adding latest version of

- awssdk.core (3.3.27.2)
- Microsoft.Net.Http (2.2.29)
- Micorosft.Bcl.Build (1.0.21)

As per this answer - [Xamain Linker Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432446/xamarin-linker-error-with-awssdk)

At the moment I am stuck, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the versunof you  VS?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.8.7

Comment: Did u find a solution for this ?I am facing the same issue